# Use powershell ssh client with custom CA bundle

Tags: networking, ssh, powershell, firewall, certificate

I need to use a windows 10 machine with powershell's ssh client to connect to a number of linux machines.
Authentication is done with user and password, no public key being sent ATM.

But I'm behind a new corporate firewall, so I need to add this firewall's certificate to the CA bundle my ssh client runs, otherwise I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\my.user> ssh user@machine.com
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
```

I can confirm the ssh server is working fine, I connect using separate pc and separate network. I had to add this new firewall's certificate to my local nodejs instance and other network-related software too. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Provide any server logs and configuration files

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how restrictive your corporate firewall is, but I would make a jump host on digital ocean; and I would run ssh on an alternate port.

1. create ubuntu host on digital ocean
2. in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` change `Port 22` to `port 80` (or whatever, port you want, 80 because no one blocks 80); also enable password authentication (`PasswordAuthentication yes`).
3. ssh to host with `ssh -p 80 digitaloceanhostip`
4. use a program like `screen` to then ssh to as many hosts as you want while keeping your session open if you get disconnected